# how to write 2 conditions in single while controller?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

i have used below code in while controller but not working in single iteration.
these 2 conditions used for text checking

```
${__javaScript("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message") == -1,)} 
&& 
${__javaScript("${textcheck2}".indexOf("Message1") == -1,)}
```

plz help me on that.how to write both condition in single while controller?
i have tried multiple ways but not working ..

Comment: Hi all, i have modified groovy instead of javascript . 2nd condition not working  please help me on that....                                                   
 # ${__groovy("${text}".indexOf("account-view-enroll-client") == -1 && ((!"${text3}").indexOf("This client is already enrolled.") == -1),)}

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both conditions into single [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) like

```
${__javaScript(("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message") == -1 && ("${textcheck1}".indexOf("Message1") == -1,)}
```

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more details.

Also as per __javaScript() function documentation:

> javaScript is not the best scripting language for performances in JMeter. If your plan requires a high number of threads it is advised to use [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) functions.

so it worth considering migrating.

Comment: ..You missed open brackets to close  "${__javaScript((" plz help me on that where i need to put close brackets. As per your suggestion , i am going to use __groovy function . I need to remove JavaScript instead of have to __groovy right ?

Comment: ${__groovy("${text}".indexOf("account-view-enroll-client") == -1 && ((!"${text3}").indexOf("This client is already enrolled.") == -1),)}

Comment: Anyone plzz help me on that? @Dmitri T